# Mouse hover results in unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a one row table that lays out a series of 6 buttons. I am preloading 12 images (2 for each button). Each button starts out with its version of a blue image. When the user hovers over any of the buttons, the image switches to the green version. When the mouse leaves the button, it turns back to blue. That part works fine. Almost.

If I am 'normal' with my mouse movements, everything is great. But in testing, if I start moving my mouse randomly and quickly, I can almost immediately generate a situation where a mouse leave event results in a button remaining green. This should never happen. The green image is supposed to display only while the mouse is hovering over the button.

I'm new to jQuery, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can anyone see it? Thanks!

Note on CSS3: I've simplified the issue slightly for this post. In the real version, each button could start out with either a blue or a green image, so I need to test for which image is displayed before I flip it. I don't think that CSS3 can do this, but if I'm wrong, I'd be open to a CSS3 solution.

```
$("#menu_row").find('button').hover(
    function() {flipColor(event.target.id);}
);

function flipColor(btn_id) {

    var image = $('#'+btn_id).find('img').get(0);

    switch (btn_id) {

        case 'btn_home' :
            if (image.src == home_green.src)
                image.src = home_blue.src;
            else image.src = home_green.src;
            break;

        case 'btn_capabilities' :
            if (image.src == capabilities_green.src) 
                image.src = capabilities_blue.src;
            else image.src = capabilities_green.src;
            break;

        case 'btn_beliefs' :
            if (image.src == beliefs_green.src) 
                image.src = beliefs_blue.src;
            else image.src = beliefs_green.src;
            break;

        case 'btn_biography' :
            if (image.src == biography_green.src) 
                image.src = biography_blue.src;
            else image.src = biography_green.src;
            break;

        case 'btn_experience' :
            if (image.src == experience_green.src) 
                image.src = experience_blue.src;
            else image.src = experience_green.src;
            break;

        case 'btn_contact' :
            if (image.src == contact_green.src) 
                image.src = contact_blue.src;
            else image.src = contact_green.src;
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table><tr id='menu_row'>
    <td id='home'>
        <button id='btn_home' class='active'>
            <img src="images/home_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>

    <td id='capabilities'>
        <button id='btn_capabilities'>
            <img src="images/capabilities_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>

    <td id='beliefs'>
        <button id='btn_beliefs'>
            <img src="images/beliefs_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>

    <td id='biography'>
        <button id='btn_biography'>
            <img src="images/biography_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>

    <td id='experience'>
        <button id='btn_experience'>
            <img src="images/experience_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>

    <td>
        <button id='btn_contact'>
            <img src="images/contact_blue.png">
        </button>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS3 for this problem?

Comment: I've simplified the issue slightly for this post. In the real version, each button could start out with either a blue or a green image, so I need to test for which image is displayed before I flip it. I don't think that CSS3 can do this, can it?

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about change the image's class, rather than change the src.

Comment: That's a good idea. What I question about that is whether I can still pre-load the images this way. There is no way that a mouse hover event will be responsive enough if it has to make a network call to get the replacement image.

Comment: How large are the images? If they are reasonably small, use sprites (i.e. a single large image with the various images laid out in a row/coil arrangement). You then just use classes (e.g. using `toggleClass`) and CSS styles to change image offsets within that.

Comment: They are very small and could be easily loaded in a single image. I've never though of doing it with offsets. Great idea. I still wonder if I will wind up right back with the same problem, though. It's worth a try, but it will take a bit of work to pull off.